# Release<Primative Type>ArrayElements in Android NDK causes "JNI: pin count" warning

Tags: java, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I am trying to write some c code in the Android NDK to take some array variables from the java application, do some mathematical analysis and return the result to java. The code I have at the moment returns the correct data but produces a warning on logcat each time the function is called:

```
JNI: pincount on array 0x423d0de0 ([F) is now x
```

The pincount keeps rising until the program eventually crashes.

As I understand it the "pin" is created when GetFloatArrayElements is called and should be removed when ReleaseFloatArrayElements is called, but clearly I am going wrong somewhere. Here is my code:

```
JNIEXPORT jfloat JNICALL
Java_net_zx82_rendertest_testHist(JNIEnv * env, jobject obj, jfloatArray dataArray, jfloatArray     gainArray, jfloatArray offsetArray)
{
//get data
jfloat *a = (*env)->GetFloatArrayElements(env, dataArray, 0);
jfloat *b = (*env)->GetFloatArrayElements(env, gainArray, 0);
jfloat *c = (*env)->GetFloatArrayElements(env, offsetArray, 0);

return a[100]*b[100]+c[100];    //do some sums

//release the data
(*env)->ReleaseFloatArrayElements(env, dataArray, a, 0);
(*env)->ReleaseFloatArrayElements(env, gainArray, b, 0);
(*env)->ReleaseFloatArrayElements(env, offsetArray, c, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the code as written, execution of the method will stop when `return` is reached, and the `ReleaseFloatArrayElements` calls will never execute.

Compute your result, store it in a temporary, and return it at the very end of the method.

In C++, you can create helper classes that auto-release the array elements when they go out of scope.  See for example the "[scoped primitive array](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libnativehelper/+/kitkat-release/include/nativehelper/ScopedPrimitiveArray.h)" classes in the Android sources.